# Setting up IPv6 ACLs on 3com 5500g to block Router Advertisment messages

Tags: ipv6, access-control-list, 3com

Is there a way to set up IPv6 ACLs on 3com 5500g switch to block RA traffic on access ports? I couldn't find settings for setting up any IPv6 ACL. Acording to guides, there should be ipv6 specific commands, but these were not available. My version on switch is  V3.03.02s168p23.

Thanks for help.

EDIT: Sorry, I gave wrong version. Fixed now.

Comment: You need at least 3.3.2p3 or higher firmware, and you need to yell at HP for not publishing the command reference updates for this.